# adding manual xml tags in oracle xml query

Tags: xml, database, oracle, oracle10g

i have written the below query in 
that i want to add some manual xml
tags to it.

```
select xmlelement("dept_list",
       xmlagg (
         xmlelement("dept",
           xmlattributes(d.deptno as "deptno"),
           xmlforest(
             d.deptno as "deptno",
             d.dname as "dname",
             d.loc as "loc",
             (select xmlagg(
                       xmlelement("emp",
                         xmlforest(
                           e.empno as "empno",
                           e.ename as "ename",
                           e.job as "job",
                           e.mgr as "mgr",
                           e.hiredate as "hiredate",
                           e.sal as "sal",
                           e.comm as "comm"
                         )
                       )
                     )
              from   emp e
              where  e.deptno = d.deptno
             ) "emp_list"
           )
         )
       )
     ).extract('*')  as "depts"
from   dept d
where  d.deptno = 10;
```

output

```
    <dept_list>
    <dept deptno="10">
    <deptno>10</deptno>
    <dname>ACCOUNTING</dname>
    <loc>NEW YORK</loc>
    <emp_list>
      <emp>
        <empno>7934</empno>
        <ename>MILLER</ename>
        <job>CLERK</job>
        <mgr>7782</mgr>
        <hiredate>1982-01-23</hiredate>
        <sal>1300</sal>
      </emp>
      <emp>
        <empno>7782</empno>
        <ename>CLARK</ename>
        <job>MANAGER</job>
        <mgr>7839</mgr>
        <hiredate>1981-06-09</hiredate>
        <sal>2450</sal>
      </emp>
      <emp>
        <empno>7839</empno>
        <ename>KING</ename>
        <job>PRESIDENT</job>
        <hiredate>1981-11-17</hiredate>
        <sal>5000</sal>
        <comm>100</comm>
      </emp>
    </emp_list>
    </dept>
    </dept_list>
```

but i required the output like this

```
**<?xml version="1.0"?>                         
<batch xmlns="urn:mclsoftware.co.uk:hunterII">
<header><count>2</count>
<originator>KALPATARU</originator>
<suppress>y</suppress>
</header>**
<dept_list>
<dept deptno="10">
<deptno>10</deptno>
<dname>ACCOUNTING</dname>
<loc>NEW YORK</loc>
<emp_list>
  <emp>
    <empno>7934</empno>
    <ename>MILLER</ename>
    <job>CLERK</job>
    <mgr>7782</mgr>
    <hiredate>1982-01-23</hiredate>
    <sal>1300</sal>
  </emp>
  <emp>
    <empno>7782</empno>
    <ename>CLARK</ename>
    <job>MANAGER</job>
    <mgr>7839</mgr>
    <hiredate>1981-06-09</hiredate>
    <sal>2450</sal>
  </emp>
  <emp>
    <empno>7839</empno>
    <ename>KING</ename>
    <job>PRESIDENT</job>
    <hiredate>1981-11-17</hiredate>
    <sal>5000</sal>
    <comm>100</comm>
  </emp>
</emp_list>
</dept>
</dept_list>
**</batch>**
```

i am using oracle database 10g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that dbmsxml procedures provide the upper element (the version tag), but do not let you add attributes to tags. For that, you need to use dbms_xmldom. Here's one [example](http://allthingsoracle.com/generating-xml-from-sql-and-plsql-part-2/), but you can search Oracle for more complete documentation.